# Metal drawable drops ALL frames when the window is occluded by other windows

Tags: metal

I have an app that displays a brief animation in a CAMetalLayer.

When my app's window is fully or at least partially visible, the animation is rendered fully and properly.

However, once the app's window gets fully occluded by another window, the animation stops rendering at some point, and when I switch back to my app's window I find it showing an intermediate frame of the animation.

I've added a presentation completion handler to each current drawable with `- [id<MTLDrawable> addPresentedHandler:`] and it does get called, however the `- [id<MTLDrawable> presentedTime]` starts giving `0` continuously on all frames after the window gets occluded. The docs say:

> MTLDrawable

> presentedTime

> The host time, in seconds, when the drawable was displayed onscreen.

> The property value is 0.0 if the drawable hasn’t been presented or if
> its associated frame was dropped.

So it looks like when the window is occluded, ALL frames get dropped. Why does this happen? Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: CoreAnimation probably stops feeding your application drawables when it's fully occluded. You should probably be handling `didChangeOcclusionStateNotification` and using `occlusionState` to figure out if you need to be rendering. A good reason to handle it properly is if later you want to port your application to iOS, OS won't let you render in the background, so you will also have to handle app going to background and foreground.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the hint!!! Obviously, you are on the right track, even though the `-[CAMetalLayer nextDrawable]` still keeps returning non-nil drawables for the occluded window, with valid drawable size etc. - there is no sign that they are somehow different from those drawables that do get rendered (when the window is not occluded). That said, I assume Metal just decides to drop those frames on a lower level. The `NSWindowDidChangeOcclusionStateNotification` notification did help to work around this problem flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: I think that sounds in line with the behavior you should expect. `CAMetalLayer` does feed you drawable, it's just that CA does not present them, since they are occluded, hence the presented time of 0.0.